# how to compare multiple rows in excel sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have table values in sheet1

```
A1  B1      C1
Id  Name    Salary
100 James   1000
200 Nathan  2000    
300 Cook    4000
400 Lie     10000
500 umer    9899
600 barbi   2090
```

I have table values in sheet2

```
A1  B1      C1   
Id  Name    Salary
250 king    4000
100 James   1000
200 Nathan  2000    
300 Cook    4000
400 Lie     10000
```

I want to compare two sheets(1 and 2) and get the result in sheet3 like

```
A1  B1      C1
Id  Name    Salary
500 umer    9899
600 barbi   2090
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `I1`:

```
=VSTACK(A1:C1,FILTER(A2:C7,COUNTIF(F2:F6,B2:B7)=0))
```

Obviously ditch the `VSTACK()` if not available and just use the `FILTER()` part.

Comment: Not working both options

Comment: @JanSeijerlin, what version of Excel have you got? If `FILTER()` is not available you would need to go to bigger lenghts to get the same result or , for example use helper column and a manual filter. Even PowerQuery would be an option.

Comment: Using ms365 only

Comment: @JanSeijerlin, then `FILTER()` should work as presented in my example. "*Not working both options*" is not telling me much.

Comment: USING        =FILTER(A2:C7,COUNTIF(F2:F6,B2:B7)=0) and getting 400 Lie  10000 row as well along with                                                                                      
 500 umer 9899
600 barbi 2090

Comment: Do you have any trailing spaces for example on `F6` or `B5` right after 'Lie'? @JanSeijerlin. The formula is working as expected (as per screenshot). The issue lays in your data.